# Ajax call returns wrong Date format in Datalist form

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, date

I have this Ajax Call function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
v
var TesterID = "<?php echo $_GET['TesterID']; ?>"; /* value der Tester erhalten */ 

        $.ajax({ /* AJAX aufrufen */
            url: 'ma_get-TesterID.php',
            type: 'get', /* Methode zum übertragen der Daten */
            data: {TesterID:TesterID}, /* Daten zu übermitteln */
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){ /* Die zurückgegebenene Daten erhalten */

                var len = response.length;

                $("#Teststart").empty(); /* Die erhaltenden Daten werden bei der ID angezeigt */
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var CID = response[i]['CID'];
                    var Datum = response[i]['Datum'];

                    $("#Teststart").append("<option value='"+Datum+"'>"+Datum+"</option>");

                }
            }
        });
});
```

The Ajax return the Dates from the Database with this Code:

```
$sqlreadZeit = "Select TOP 10 CID,Datum from DB.dbo.xxx where TesterID = '".$_GET['TesterID']."' order by Datum DESC";
                $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlreadZeit);
                $zeiten_arr = array();
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $CID = $row['CID'];

                $Datum = $row['Datum']->format('d.m.Y H:m:s');

                $zeiten_arr[] = array("CID" => $CID, "Datum" => $Datum);

                }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($zeiten_arr); /* Ausgabe printen die Erhalten werden soll */
```

These are the results when I execute the query in SQL:

[image]

But in the Datalist it shows the date like this, seems like rounded.

[image]

In which part could be the problem? I don't see it.

I use MS SQL Server and moment-with-locales.js in a other Javascript function.

Comment: Please set timezone to your local time in php `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` also check your database timezone using `SELECT NOW()` if it is your time zone then no prob else run `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`

Comment: i have mssql and not mysql

Comment: maybe something to do with moment-with-locales.js? i use it in a other JavaScript function.

Comment: try selected your local time using each language ? and   see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Change your date format to `'d.m.Y H:i:s'` and format your dates using next statement: `$Datum = $row['Datum']->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');` (`'i'` is for minutes with leading zeros).
- Take a look at `ReturnDatesAsStrings` [connection option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-2017) when you call `sqlsrv_connect()`. When this option is `true`, date/time values are returned as strings.

Comment: @Daniel Glad to help.